# What is the difference between different options for 'ls' colored output in zsh?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, environment-variables, ls

I want to display colored output for the 'ls' command in the terminal for my MAC but I do not understand the differences between some of the methods. On some articles and reddit posts I saw people adding the following to their .zshrc configuration:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -G'
alias ll='ls -alG'
```

According to the man pages, setting the CLICOLOR environment variable to 1 should do the same thing as using the -G option for ls. So what is the point of adding the -G option to the aliases if the CLICOLOR environment variable is already set? Additionally, what is the --color option? Does this option do the same thing as the -G option for ls?

Comment: The internet must not be right everytime, the man page is right with a greater probability. So it seems that you are just right, there is no need to specify both, `CLICOLOR` and `-G`. Your question relates to the bsd-style `ls` (which is included in MacOS) and not to gnu-style `ls`, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2904, so I adjusted the question tags accordingly.